# What is cmake_install.cmake

Tags: cmake, installation

I wrote a very simple HelloWorld.c program and ran Cmake. It created a `cmake_install.cmake` file in my build directory. Can somebody explain to me why CMake generated the file cmake_install.cmake?  What is it's purpose and how can I use it?

CMakelists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
PROJECT(FirstExample)
add_executable(prog first.c)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is generated will depend highly on what your CMakeLists.txt file contains.  Can you add the contents of that file to your question?

Comment: Added my code... Basic example .. Thank you for answer.:)

Comment: This is among many other by products of running cmake. Running cmake creates makefile and its like files. We generally dont have to directly use these files.

Comment: It's been a while, but it would be helpful if this question included the contents of cmake_install.cmake, I would have liked to see what a "hello world" cmake example would generate for this file. If it helps, [here's a hello world example that genreates this file](https://github.com/cognitivewaves/CMake-VisualStudio-Example).

Answer (score 21):

You generally don't use cmake_install.cmake directly.  From the [v3.12 page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/install.html) it states:

> The install() command generates a file, cmake_install.cmake, inside
> the build directory, which is used internally by the generated install
> target and by [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/module/CPack.html?highlight=cpack).

With your current CMakeLists.txt, the generated file doesn't do much.  To create a useful install you would need to add more `INSTALL` commands to your `CMakeLists.txt` using the syntax below.

```
INSTALL(TARGETS targets... [EXPORT <export-name>]
    [[ARCHIVE|LIBRARY|RUNTIME|FRAMEWORK|BUNDLE|
      PRIVATE_HEADER|PUBLIC_HEADER|RESOURCE]
     [DESTINATION <dir>]
     [INCLUDES DESTINATION [<dir> ...]]
     [PERMISSIONS permissions...]
     [CONFIGURATIONS [Debug|Release|...]]
     [COMPONENT <component>]
     [OPTIONAL] [NAMELINK_ONLY|NAMELINK_SKIP]
    ] [...])
```

For further reading on this command, check out the [documentation site](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html?highlight=install) and [wiki](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/Install-Commands).

If it's desired to manually execute the script as stated by Nic30g the 3.12 page states that `cmake -P` accepts the following variables:

**COMPONENT**
Set this variable to install only a single [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/module/CPack.html?highlight=cpack) component as opposed to all of them. For example, if you only want to install the Development component, run

```
 cmake -DCOMPONENT=Development -P cmake_install.cmake
```

**BUILD_TYPE**
Set this variable to change the build type if you are using a multi-config generator. For example, to install with the Debug configuration, run

```
 cmake -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake.
```

**DESTDIR**
This is an environment variable rather than a CMake variable. It allows you to change the installation prefix on UNIX systems. See [DESTDIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/envvar/DESTDIR.html#envvar:DESTDIR) for details.

Comment: But can it do anything? I'm in Visual Studio and I don't see an "install" project; though cmake_install.cmake is there.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question.

Answer (score 19):

As previous answer tells, the `cmake_install.cmake` contains the commands generated by install command from your `CMakeLists.txt`.

You can execute it by `cmake -P cmake_install.cmake` and it performs the installation  of your project even on windows.

https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-April/013657.html