# Avoid creation of cmake_install.cmake file

Tags: cmake

I have several small personal projects that I execute directly from the build directory, and never are going "to be installed". Is there a way to avoid the creation of the [cmake_install.cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669919/what-is-cmake-install-cmake) file in my build directory each time I run cmake?

I have seen the [install documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html) that explain how to configure install, but not how to disable the install procedure. Is there a cmake command line argument or cmake rule to avoid the creation of file cmake_install.cmake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your project's CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES True)
```

This is a [documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES.html) CMake variable.